# How is this URL being redirected?

Tags: redirect

I came across this coupon website that uses a URL structure something like the below one for its affiliate links.

`https://example.com/?offers=/http://tracking.affiliate-link.com&aff_id=123`

When clicked on the link, it will be automatically redirected from `example.com` to `http://tracking.affiliate-link.com&aff_id=123`

I know there are a lot of plugins for WordPress that let you cloak the affiliate links. But those plugins require you to manually add the links in the plugins page first.

I was wondering how to achieve the above shown redirect. That is, simply add `https://example.com/?offers=/` in front of the actual affiliate link and it should be redirected.

Is there anyway I can achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `?offers=/http://tracking.affiliate-link.com&aff_id=123` after your link and then check in the destination page (in this case the homepage) if is set `$_GET['offers']`, and in the case that it is, redirect to the content of the var, which is the url.

In the Wordpress system I would create a page called "Offers" that would be in `example.com/offers`. You can create a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/) attached to this page, and there check if the link sent by get parameters is what you want, and in case it is, redirect the user.

A simple page template would be something like this:

```
<?php  /*   Template Name: Offers   */ ?>
<?php if(isset($_GET['offers'])){
    wp_redirect( $_GET['offers'] );
    exit;
} ?>
```